# How do you group arrays with differing values in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have variables with different value types assigned. I want to display them on the same table view in separate sections. What do I need to assign to my variable "array"? Here is my code.

```
    let sections = ["Custom Library", "Mastered Words", "Library"]
    var list:[AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
    var mastered = ["test"]
    var default = ["test"]


    var arrray = [
        [AnyObject](),
        [String](),
        [String]()
        ]

override func viewDidLoad() { 
            super.viewDidLoad()

    array = [
         list,
         mastered,
         defaultLibrary
        ]
```

Comment: Basically, don't. Don't use AnyObject and don't use arrays of Any, AnyObject, or multiple unrelated types. Start over with a more sensible implementation of your data model.

Comment: I wouldn't even try. Instead, make a `TableRowItem` protocol (which describes how an object presents itself in a table), then make a `TableSection` struct, which stores a title and an array of `TableRowItem`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need to have a model struct for your collection of data, probably following code might help:

```
struct myDataModel {
    var listData: [AnyObject]
    var masteredData: [String]
    var defaultLibraryData: [String]
}

override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var array = myDataModel(listData: list, masteredData: mastered, defaultLibraryData: defaultLibrary)
    //though now "array" seems to be a bad convention for this var now.
```